# How to 301 alternative language sites to english?

Tags: mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

My client has a website that has english, german, spanish and french sites. They are just simple folder structures on the server inside the public_html directory eg. /de, /fr, /en and /es

They have decided to remove the other languages and only have english but i have quite a few pages that need 301 redirecting.

I already use a mod_rewrite for doing pretty URLs throughout.

What would be the best way to redirect the alt language pages to the english pages without disrupting the pretty URLs?

eg. `fr/news/news-article` -> `en/news/news-article`

I already have:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/news?$ $1/news.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this RewriteRule line on top of all other Rewrite rules in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:de|fr|es)(/.*|)$ /en$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

This will redirect (with R=301) every `/fr/bla/bla` or `/de/bla/bla` or `/es/bla/bla` to `/en/bla/bla`